# Find color depending on integer value - quick algorithm

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I build some app which is calculating colors to gradient depend of some value.
I used d3.js to calculate color, but i recognized this function is really slow - it is executing in 80ms (40.000 times is this function executing). This is to big for me ( i using this many times)

```
var findColor = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110]).range(['#a50026 ','#d73027 ','#f46d43 ','#fdae61 ','#fee08b ','#ffffbf ','#d9ef8b ','#a6d96a ','#66bd63 ','#1a9850 ','#006837 ','#006837 ']);
```

Can You tell me what is the better solution for this? I need faster idea.

Is the switch with 50 case's ll be better, faster?

Comment: take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrjwmnbL/3/ I made a few tests, but the results are kind of too good to be true; you might want to test that in your application, in real-case scenarios, with real data.

Comment: (3x faster in Edge, and after a warmup, about 10-20x faster in FF && Chrome :O) I'm afraid, that this might just be the result of some clever optimization of the benchmark.

Comment: @Thomas Yours jsfidle is awesome. Thanks, for Yours help. Add this in "answer" so then I could accept this

Comment: @Thomas I have one problem with Your code, why when I'm passsing value higher than 0-1, so my rand() are not diveded by 110, I have an error? For example i tried with rand()/50 and thats not working

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't reckon a decent computer using a modern browser would take 80ms to perform that function.

This is *not* an answer (in the sense that I'm not providing any faster alternative), but I had to write it as an answer because I want to use the snippet (which I can't use in a comment) to show you how fast is this function:

In the following snippet, this function is executed 10000 times. In my (quite old) computer, with Chrome, it takes 21ms to run all the loop. Click "run code snippet" to check.

```js
var t1 = performance.now()

var findColor = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110])
    .range(['#a50026 ','#d73027 ','#f46d43 ','#fdae61 ','#fee08b ','#ffffbf ','#d9ef8b ','#a6d96a ','#66bd63 ','#1a9850 ','#006837 ','#006837 ']);

for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
findColor(Math.random()*110)
}

var t2 = performance.now()

console.log("Time: " + (t2 - t1) + " miliseconds");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE**: the OP edited the question, explaining that 80ms refers to 40000 times. That is roughly the same performance of the above snippet looping 40000 times.

Comment: I'm clicking it several times, the record so far is 18ms for this 10000x loop. The worse time was 40ms.

Comment: Well, there you have it. It's already pretty fast. So how are you getting 80ms just running it once?

Comment: I had 80ms running it about 4000 * 50 so 200000

Comment: Wow, that's a very different situation! I suggest that you add this information on your question. Btw, 80ms for two hundred thousand times seems to be a decent performance.

Comment: I make a mistake, not 200.000 but 40.000, but it takes about 80ms - this is to big for me